# super protected java

Tags: java, protected, super, inheritance

A question about inheritance in java...

```
class Base {
    private int val = 10;
}

class Derive extends Base{
    public void setVal(int value) {
        super.val = value;
    }
}
```

Since we can change the `private` field in super class using `super` keyword in the subclass, why should we use `protected` to declare fields in super class?

Comment: first of all, as the answer states this won't compile, you can't access private fields, second even if you could, please use setters/getters even internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that. The code you've given doesn't compile, unless `Derive` is declared as a nested class within `Base` (which is a pretty rare case).

You should be getting an error like this:

```
error: val has private access in Base
```

Comment: yes, thanks. I used nested static class for test. It supposed that I should never do this to test accessibility again.

Answer (score 0):

super is an reference variable which is used to call parents constructor.

Comment: super is most definitely not a variable.

Comment: @matiash sorry reference variable

Answer (score 0):

Check your code you can never access private out side the class even if you have inherited that class.